# Okta redirect URI when used as OpenID IDP provider in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect, okta

I'm trying to set up Okta as an OpenID Connect provider in my Azure AD B2C tenant. Something is off with my configuration. It's throwing an error when I test the B2C user flow saying:

```
Error Code: invalid_request
Description: The 'redirect_uri' parameter must be a Login redirect URI in the client app
```

Here are the steps I followed

### Okta

- Create application OpenID Connect application
  [image]
- Assign users to this application
- Take note of client ID and secret
  [image]
- Based on [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin#change-identity-provider-redirect-urls), I set the sign-in redirect URI to

> https://**B2CTenantName**.b2clogin.com/**B2C tenant ID**/oauth2/authresp
> https://colinwurtzb2c.b2clogin.com/eb178344-61bd-4822-95cf-7a251aaba527/oauth2/authresp

### Azure

- Create a new App Registration and set redirect URI to `http://localhost:3000`
- Added new OpenID Connect provider
- Filled out this form with client ID, metadata URL, and client secret provided by Okta
  [image]
- Created a user flow called B2C_1_SignInOkta
- Assign the newly added OpenID Connect Okta provider to this user flow.
- Attempt to run the user flow, but it immediately redirects to Okta with error listed above.
  [image]

[image: List item]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to be consistent which URL pattern / tenant identifier you use. If you set up Okta application with https://colinwurtzb2c.b2clogin.com/eb178344-61bd-4822-95cf-7a251aaba527/oauth2/authresp (using tenant Id) then you need to open your user flow also using tenant Id. Your screen shows the default Azure Portal option with tenant name, so the URL starts with https://colinwurtzb2c.b2clogin.com/colinwurtzb2c.onmicrosoft.com/(...).
My guess is that in this case AAD B2C makes a request to Okta using https://colinwurtzb2c.b2clogin.com/colinwurtzb2c.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp which is different then the one you set up and hence the error.
So, either set up Okta with the URL including tenant name or use tenant Id while running AAD B2C user flow.

Comment: Thank you - that was it. Had to make a few other tweaks as well once I got passed that error.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to being consistent with the link, I had to add a few scopes in the custom IDP screen and map `email` to `User ID` in the claims mapping section.

[image]